# "Failed to execute script" error while try run program from search

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created .exe file with PyInstaller. My program works without an error when i run it directly. But when i try to run it from file [search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVABL.png) it returns "Failed to execute script" error. It doesn't make sense, i do not understand it. Also i can't see any other error -whether console mode or not-

Used imports:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from course_grabber import getCourseClasses,getCourseCodes
import random
from itertools import combinations
from profilim import Ui_Profilim
from dersler import Ui_dersPlaniPencere
from vt_islemleri import *
from threading import Thread
from webbrowser import open as tarayici_ac
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
import gc
import sys
import sqlite3 as sql
from course import Course
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I tried a lot of things in code and pyinstaller. It's about permissions. When i run as administrator it worked. Program could not open external the database without administrator perm.